# JGit Java issues connecting via ssh

Tags: java, git, ssh, jgit

Hi Guys i have a problem connecting to a provided ssh server using the jGit library. The current issue i have is "Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Destination path "Testing" already exists and is not an empty directory" keeping in mind that i have looked at http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/ and other stackoverflow posts which their answers have not fixed my issue. Would anyone perhaps assist in what i am doing wrong?

```
    try
    {
        String user = "username";
        String host = "ssh://"+user+"@the.server.address/";
        String password = "password";

        SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory()
        {
            @Override
            protected void configure(Host hc, Session session)
            {
                session.setPassword(password);
            }
        };

        CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();

        cloneCommand.setURI(host);
        cloneCommand.setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void configure(Transport transport)
            {
                SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
                sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(sshSessionFactory);
            }
        });
        cloneCommand.call();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }
```

The error i am getting:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Destination path "THE LOCAL DIR PATH" already exists and is not an empty directory at
org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.verifyDirectories(CloneCom‌​mand.java:243)at
org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:179‌​) at 
assignment.MainFXMLDocumentController.buttonWidgetViewAction‌​(MainFXMLDocumentCon‌​troller.java:136) ... 58 more
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack strace.

Comment: Please **edit** the original question and amend the stack trace so that is easily readable.

Comment: ok it has been updated

Comment: The stack trace does not match your question. Are you getting a `JGitInternalException` or an `InvalidRemoteException`?

Comment: It is now a JGitInternalException

Comment: The message says 'Destination path already exists and is not an empty directory', meaning that, well, the local destination directory is not empty. You need to specify a non-existing or empty directory with `CloneCommand::setDirectory`.

Comment: That has been done although, i get the same error. It seems like it is creating a directory then throwing this error. Keep in mind downloading from Git's test repo works fine

Comment: JGit has tests cases for cloning into non-empty directories, thus I doubt that this is a JGit problem. Can you make sure that the destination directory is empty, i.e. by asserting that `directory.listFiles()` is `null` or has a length of zero? Also, you may want to debug-step into `CloneCommand::call()` and follow the call to `verifyDirectories` to see what is going on.